# mlabwrap setup Mac OS X

Tags: python, matlab, installation, mlabwrap

I have been trying to install the mlabwrap Python library, but keep on running into the following error when I run the setup.py file using the command python setup.py install in the terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 130, in <module>
    queried_version, queried_dir, queried_platform_dir = matlab_params(cmd, WINDOWS, extra_args)
  File "setup.py", line 93, in matlab_params
    error = call(cmd, **extra_args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I have done some investigation, and found the following forum post: https://sourceforge.net/p/mlabwrap/mailman/message/29077359/ to resolve the issue. Following the advice in this thread, I changed the following things in the setup.py file:

```
__version__ = '7.3'
```

and

```
MATLAB_DIR = '/Applications/MATLAB_R2015a.app'
```

I have a feeling that the problem is related to finding the directory that matlab is located in, but I seem to be unable to resolve this. I didn't change my $PATH variable because I was a little confused by the advice given in the thread. Any insight would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In order to install mlabwrap, you must modify the setup.py file to:

```
MATLAB_COMMAND = '/Applications/MATLAB_R2015a.app/bin/matlab'     # specify a full path if not in PATH
MATLAB_VERSION = 7.3      # e.g: 6 (one of (6, 6.5, 7, 7.3))
                            #      7.3 includes later versions as well
MATLAB_DIR= '/Applications/MATLAB_R2015a.app/'           # e.g: '/usr/local/matlab'; 'c:/matlab6'
PLATFORM_DIR='maci64'           # e.g: 'glnx86'; r'win32/microsoft/msvc60'
EXTRA_COMPILE_ARGS=None     # e.g: ['-G']
```

The parameters may change depending on what version of MATLAB you are using and what operating system you are using.